# Salesforce Bulk API batch download with Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, salesforce

I have an async Python script that creates a bulk API job/batch in Salesforce. After the batch is complete I then download the csv file for processing.

**Here's my problem**: A streaming download for a ~300 MB csv file using Python can take 3+ minutes using this asynchronous code:

> If you're familiar with Salesforce bulk jobs, you can enter your information
>   into the variables below and download your batch results for testing. This is a working example of code provided you enter the necessary information.

```
import asyncio, aiohttp, aiofiles
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from credentials import credentials as cred

sf_data_path = 'C:/Users/[USER NAME]/Desktop/'
job_id = '[18 DIGIT JOB ID]'
batch_id = '[18 DIGIT BATCH ID]'
result_id = '[18 DIGIT RESULT ID]'
instance_name = '[INSTANCE NAME]'
result_url = f'https://{instance_name}.salesforce.com/services/async/45.0/job/{job_id}/batch/{batch_id}/result/{result_id}'

sf = Salesforce(username=['SALESFORCE USERNAME'],
                password=['SALESFORCE PASSWORD'],
                security_token=['SALESFORCE SECURITY TOKEN'],
                organizationId=['SALESFORCE ORGANIZATION ID'])

async def download_results():
    err = None
    retries = 3
    status = 'Not Downloaded'
    for _ in range(retries):
        try:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(url=result_url,
                                       headers={"X-SFDC-Session": sf.session_id, 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'},
                                       timeout=300) as resp:
                    async with aiofiles.open(f'{sf_data_path}_DOWNLOAD_.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
                        while True:
                            chunk = await resp.content.read(10485760)  # = 10Mb
                            if not chunk:
                                break
                            await outfile.write(chunk)
                    status = 'Downloaded'
        except Exception as e:
            err = e
            retries -= 1
            status = 'Retrying'
            continue
        else:
            break
    else:
        status = 'Failed'
        return err, status, retries

asyncio.run(download_results())
```

However, if I download the result of the batch in the Developer Workbench: https://workbench.developerforce.com/asyncStatus.php?jobId='[18 DIGIT JOB ID]' the same file might download in 5 seconds.

[image]

There is obviously something going on here that I'm missing. I know that the Workbench uses PHP, is this functionality even available with Python? I figured the async calls would make this download quickly, but that doesn't seem to make it download as fast as the functionality in the browser. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try curl request to get the csv. This method is as quick as you see in the workbench.
More information you can read here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/query_walkthrough.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/query_get_job_results.htm#example_locator